useState is not updating in reactjs, although backend is proper
This is my react code for Protected Route:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setisAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    const checkALog = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/checkAuth", {
          credentials: "include",
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Response from server:", data); 
        if (data.message === "authenticated") {
          setisAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
          setisAuthenticated(false);
        }
    }
    checkALog();

    console.log(isAuthenticated);

  return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;


I am getting false as the console message when i did console.log(isAuthenticated); . And the backend is properly giving the message in data as "authenticated".
Any suggestions? How can I fix this?
Tried to ask chatgpt but it didn't help me.

checkALog is an async function which basically means that it takes some time to get its result. In this case, when you use console.log(isAuthenticated) you still have default value of isAuthenticated

@Othan27 I tried awaiting the checkALog() function. but i am still getting the value as false in the console. How can i fix this? Because of this problem, i am unable to navigate among the protected routes

useState doesn't change the direct value. In react every state is changes when there is any event performed. but there is not event call you have just called you function.
you could achieve this without useState.


import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
    const isAuthenticated = false;

    const checkALog = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/checkAuth", {
          credentials: "include",
        });
        isAuthenticated = false;
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Response from server:", data); 
        if (data.message === "authenticated") {
          isAuthenticated = true;
        }
    }
    checkALog();

    console.log(isAuthenticated);

  return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;




Thanks for the solution Nitesh Mangla, but isn't there a way to do it using useState? I just want to make the concepts clear

i am not saying to use useState, because you could achieve this without useState as i mentioned in my code.

Actually the problem with this code lies in the asynchronous nature of checkALog(). Since isAuthenticated is a local variable initialized with false, its value won't change before the component renders, leading to ProtectedRoute always rendering <Navigate to="/" />.

The good practice always is to use useEffect hook whenever you are making any async calls or fetches. Try calling your function checkALog() inside the useEffect hook.
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setisAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    const checkALog = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/checkAuth", {
          credentials: "include",
        });
        isAuthenticated = false;
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Response from server:", data); 
        if (data.message === "authenticated") {
            setisAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
           setisAuthenticated(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkALog();
    }, []);

    console.log(isAuthenticated);

    return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Navigate to="/" />
};

export default ProtectedRoute;


Thanks for the response, but still it is not working. I am still getting false in my console.
